# MERGE vs DELETE/INSERT in Oracle 10g

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have a procedure that is run often (~1000x every 5 mins) in Oracle 10g.  The basic idea is to refresh data in a table based on the PK.

Which has a better performance in terms of IO/CPU load on the database?  `DELETE` by PK then `INSERT` or a `MERGE` on PK?

Comment: With MERGE you can do INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs. Not sure what you're asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MERGE is almost always slower then special crafted DELETEs with BULK INSERTs.
Its only more convient to use in some cases.

On the other hand, if you don't use any tricks to speedup your queries performance will be almost the same.